# Having issues with Android Studio Emulators

Tags: android, windows, firebase, android-studio

I have connected my physical device and when I troubleshoot it its visible but when I try to run the program it says no device.
how can i solve this problem?

I have also tried using virtual devices but it throws an error that I should download an emulator.
I have downloaded the emulator but it says there is a problem with HAXM

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 ways

1. Physical: You must check developer option(tap 10 time on build version)
2. Android studio: Android studio Emulator, this way you must install HAXM
3. Other emulator: Install apps likes Genymotion